# Why is .contains returning false when I add a duplicate?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I'm writing a simple method to add an object to an ArrayList if it doesn't already contain it. I'm using the .contains method, but for some reason, when I add a duplicate of an object to the ArrayList, the .contains method returns false, even though I have already added the same object to the ArrayList.

This is my `City` class:

```
class City {
  private String name, country;
  //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

When I have an `ArrayList` like this:

```
List<City> destinations = new ArrayList<>();
```

with one object added to it

```
destinations.add(new City("Edmonston", "CA"));
```

If I check if it contains a duplicate object like this, it returns false

```
destinations.contains(new City("Edmonston", "CA"))
```

Here's the full code:

Main method
[image: main method],

Output
[image: output]

City class 
[image: City class]

Trip class
[image: Trip class]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add text instead of links to images, especially those that are hard to read. I can barely see your Trip class

Comment: The problem is probably that you haven't overriden your `equals` and `hashCode` methods. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), it uses the `Objects.equals` method to compare elements. [`Objects.equals(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) first checks if either of the arguments are `null`, and then uses `a.equals(b)` to check if they're the same

Comment: Is looping not an option for you?

Comment: @user in what case would I have to override the hashCode method? I tested just overriding the equals method and it works fine.

Comment: @gili.g When you're using `HashSet`, `HashMap`, etc., they use the hash code of your object

Comment: @user understood. thanks!

Comment: @gili.g You're welcome. By the way, you should see what Grégori Fernandes de Lima said and maybe use a `Set` instead of a `List`. When you use a Set, it automatically checks for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation of List#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) given below:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that Objects.equals(o, e).

Thus, you need to override `equals` method in `class City`. You can do it as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    City other = (City) obj;
    return Objects.equals(name, other.name) && Objects.equals(country, other.country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `contains()` to work properly, you have to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your class. If you don't, the base for equality is that the objects referenced are one and the same.

For example:

```
City c1 = new City("London", "UK") ;
City c2 = new City("London", "UK") ;
System.out.println(c1.equals(c2)) ;    // prints false
c2 = c1 ;
System.out.println(c1.equals(c2)) ;    // prints true
```

EDIT: To override the `equals()` method, see Arvind Kumar Avinash's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way the `contains` method works, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), is that it uses `Objects.equals(o, e)` where `o` is the object you're checking exists in the `ArrayList` and `e` is every element in the array.

[`Objects.equals(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) first checks if either of the arguments are `null`, and then uses `a.equals(b)` to check if they're the same.

By default, the `equals` method in the `Object` just does `a == b`, which only returns true if `a` is the exact same object as `b`, i.e., `a` and `b` both refer to the same location in memory and doesn't care about the variables inside the object.

```
City c = new City("foo", "bar");
c == new City("foo", "bar") //not true
c == c //true
```

Because of this default implementation of `equals`:

```
City c = new City("foo", "bar");
c.equals(new City("foo", "bar")) //not true
c.equals(c) //true
```

Therefore, you need to override the `equals` method in your `City` class so that you can check whether 2 City objects are equal. Arvind Kumar Avinash's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332490/11882002) provides a way to do this.

However, every collection can implement the `contains` and similar methods differently. `HashSet`s may use the hash code of objects to compare them. Therefore, it's important to also override the hashCode method for your class.

```
public int hashCode() {
  return Objects.hash(name, country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert only one City object in your list, use HashSet and override the equals() and hashCode() methods from Object class in your City class.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<City> list = new HashSet<City>();

    list.add(new City("Edmonston", "CA"));
    list.add(new City("Edmonston", "CA"));
    list.add(new City("Edmonston", "CA"));

    System.out.println(list); //Edmonston in CA
}
```

And your City class:

```
class City {

private String name, country;

 public City(String s1, String s2) {
        this.name = s1;
        this.country = s2;
    }

 @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof City)
         return this.name == ((City) obj).name & this.country == ((City) obj).country;
     else
         return false;
}



 @Override
public int hashCode() {

     return this.country.hashCode() + this.name.hashCode();

}


 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " in " + this.country;
    }
}
```