# Why are highlighted items lost after scrolling in recylerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, highlight

I want to highlight the item when the action mode is active in the adapter class. I am able to do so but the highlight state is gone after scrolling. I have tried various solutions but I don't know understand why this is happening?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

   
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 
     
     public void bind(Items viewHolder_item) {     

       
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                isSelectMode = true;
                if (viewHolder_item.getIsSelect()){
                    
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    item.get(position).setSelect(false);
                    selectedList.remove(item.get(position));
                } else {
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    item.get(position).setSelect(true);
                    selectedList.add(item.get(position));
                }
                if (selectList.size() == 0){
                    isSelectMode = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isSelectMode){
                    if (viewHolder_item.getIsSelect()){
                        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        item.get(position).setSelect(false);
                        selectedList.remove(item.get(position));
                    } else {
                                                  
                       itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                       item.get(position).setSelect(true);   
                       selectedList.add(item.get(position));                      
                    }
                    if (selectList.size() == 0){
                        isSelectMode = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

No matter which solution is implemented, the result is always the same. The highlighted color is gone after scrolling. Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: in your code you work with both backgroundColor and backgroundResourse. try using just one. also in onBindViewHolder instead of calling getadapterposition() you can simply use position provided by the method

Comment: thanks for the answer but the result is same even with those changes.

Comment: I have edited above the question as well to show you the implementation.

Comment: add a Log.d() inside the firsts if statement in your onBindViewHolder method to see if the contains clause is working correctly i.e. to find out if the error occurs on binding or on setting the red color

Comment: I have added `Log.e("TAG", " contains " + selectedList.contains(items.get(position)));` in the if block as seen above. It always returns false even if you highlight an item and scroll back up.

Comment: ahaa, so thats the problem. im sure there is some reason why contains isnt working in your usecase

Comment: Is there any way that you suggest? I have tried everything that I could, but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238737/discussion-between-quealegriamasalegre-and-a-awasi).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take an alternative approach to solve your problem. In your Item object add a boolean field called `public boolean isSelected=false` then just set that field to true inside your `items` list using `items.get(position).isSelected=true` when an item is clicked and then use this field in order to evaluate which state each item should be in, instead of using your `selectedList`. you actually wont need this list anymore.

So now you just have to modify your on bindViewHolder as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Items item=items.get(position);
            
        if (!item.getIsSelect()){
               holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    isSelectMode = true;
                    if (item.getIsSelect()){
                        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        items.get(position).setSelect(false);
                        selectedList.remove(items.get(position));
                    } else {
                        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        items.get(position).setSelect(true);
                        selectedList.add(items.get(position));
                    }
                    if (selectList.size() == 0){
                        isSelectMode = false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isSelectMode){
                        if (item.getIsSelect()){
                            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            items.get(position).setSelect(false);
                            selectedList.remove(items.get(position));
                        } else {
                                                      holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        items.get(position).setSelect(true);                         
                        }
                        if (selectList.size() == 0){
                            isSelectMode = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

btw. you dont need to add isSelect to the constructor of Items as this should be an ephemeral session specific variable

there are a bunch of instances that can make contains not work as you would expect we would probably have to dive into your Item object to find a cause here is just one link [Why is .contains returning false when I add a duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332371/why-is-contains-returning-false-when-i-add-a-duplicate)

Comment: I am afraid it is giving the same result as before. I have been trying various ways but couldn't do so.

Comment: that makes no sense. can you please add the log inside the if statement again and log the isSelect() variable. also in your fragment class i cannot see where you create the items object could you please show that

Comment: I have added the items creation in the fragment class.

Comment: As for this statement `Log.e("TAG","isSelect " + item.IsSelect());` it always returns false like before.

Comment: sorry I obviously forgot to add setSelect to my code. my bad, doing it now. try again and let me know

Comment: This is again giving the same result I don't understand. Every solution is leading to same outcome.

Comment: what this is really strange. have you checked the logs? I dont see how it can return false. I just changed something in the code, try again please

Comment: I have added the log info in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

A few additions to the existing answer:

1. Treat your Adapter data as *non-mutable*. Do NOT mutate data inside the adapter. The Adapter needs to *well... adapt* data from a Model into a View (Holder). It keeps track of where each data belongs in terms of positioning, and that's pretty much all it needs to do (aside from inflating the views naturally).
2. If you supply a list of `Thing`, where `isSelected` is not part of the model, but rather part of your need to keep *track* of whether the user has selected it or not, then create a simple data class like

```
data class ThingSelection(val thing: Thing, val isSelected: Boolean)
```

And use that in your adapter instead of just a `List<Thing>`, use `List<ThingSelection>`.

3. Do not do what you do in the `onBindViewHolder`. All you should do there is

```
val item = getItem(position)
holder.bind(item)
```

It's the ViewHolder's job to set its properties, background color, etc. based on your business rules.

If your "item" is a `ThingSelection` then the viewHolder's bind method can do

`if (item.isSelected) { ... }`

Pass anything else you need to this method as well, `bind(...)` is whatever you need it to be.

#### What to do when the user changes the item selection?

You have a click listener, but *don't mutate* data, have your callback/listener pass *what happened* to the caller.

I imagine in your viewHolder bind method you'd do something like:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
   externalListenerThatTheAdapterReceivedFromTheOutside.onThingClicked(thing, thing.isSelected)
}
```

It's this external listener's responsibility to:

1. Do what it takes (possibly pass it directly to a ViewModel so it work on this new event), to ensure the adapter receives the new data (now where the Thing.isSelected is correct given what the user did).
2. Ensure the new immutable list is supplied to the adapter so the adapter can compute its new data and update (hint: use `ListAdapter<T, K>` with a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>`, it makes your life easier.

#### UPDATE: Data Class

```
data class ItemWithSelection(val item: Item, val isSelected: Boolean)
```

Then change your adapter to be:

```
class YourAdapter(): ListAdapter<ItemWithSelection, YourViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback()) {
  // You only need to override these
    
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): YourViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false) // or use ViewBinding, whatever.
        return YourViewHolder(view) // you can pass more stuff if you need here, like a listener...
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bindData(item, item.isSelected) //Item is of type ItemWithSelection...
    }
}

// Somewhere in your ViewHolder...
fun bindData(item: ItemWithSelection, isSelected: Boolean) {
   // do what it needs, e.g.:
   if (isSelected) { ... } 
}


// You also need a DiffUtilCallback...
internal class DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ItemWithSelection>() {

    internal class DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ItemWithSelection>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ItemWithSelection, newItem: ItemWithSelection) = oldItem.item.xxx == newItem.item.xxx

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ItemWithSelection, newItem: ItemWithSelection) = oldItem == newItem
    }
```

With all that wired up...

In your `ViewModel` or "layer where you get the data" (most likely *not the fragment/activity*) provide a `List<ItemWithSelection>`...

How to construct this *really* depends on how you store what is selected.

But let's say you have two lists for the sake of simplicity:

```
val all: List<Item>
val selected: List<Item>
```

When it's time to produce a list for the UI, you could (note: I'm gonna assume you use Coroutines... you pick your own flavor of asynchronous/reactive programming:

```
class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {

fun getYourListWithSelections() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Computation) {//for e.g.
            val tempSelection = mutableListOf<ItemWithSelection>()
            all.mapTo(tempSelection) {
                    ItemWithSelection(item = it, isSelected = selection.contains(it))
                }

           // Assuming you have a MutableLiveData somewhere in this viewmodel...
           _uiState.postValue(SomeSealedClass.ListAvailable(tempSelection))
        }
}
```

This is naturally observed from the Fragment...

```
class YourFragment: Fragment() {

  fun observe() {
       viewModel.uiState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { viewState ->
            when (viewState) {
                is SomeSealedClass.ListAvailable -> adapter.submitList(viewState.items.toMutableList())//need to pass a new list or ListAdapter won't refresh the list.
                else ... //exercise for the reader ;)
            }
        })
  }

}
```

All that is really missing here are the boiler plate stuff.

1. How does the ViewHolder (which sets a `click listener` on the View pass the info back to the ViewModel?
   Supply your adapter with a Listener of your choice:

```
interface ItemClickListener {
  fun onItemClicked(val item: Item, val isSelected: Boolean)
}
```

Implement that and pass it to your adapter when you create it:

```
class YourAdapter(private val listener: ItemClickListener): ListAdapter<ItemWithSelection, YourViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback()) {
```

And pass it in your fragment:

```
class YourFragment: Fragment() {

private val listener = object : ItemClickListener {
   fun onItemClicked(val item: Item, val isSelected: Boolean) {
      // pass it directly, it's the VM job to deal with this and produce a new list via LiveData.
      viewModel.onItemClicked(item, isSelected)
   }
}
val adapter = YourAdapter(listener)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I moved the data from adapter as you suggested and changed it in above code as well but I am confused about the 2nd point about simple data class. I don't know how to create and use one. If you can explain with bit of code that would be really helpful.