# save text file in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I want to save text file in sqlite android but it is giving an error `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:` at line `long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
            + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
            + POSITION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + TXT_FILE + " BLOB NOT NULL, "
            + _ID + " TEXT NOT NULL)";


    db.execSQL(create_table);

}

 public boolean add_txt_file(String id, byte[] txt_file) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(_ID,id);
        cv.put(TXT_FILE,txt_file);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        if (result == -1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

     boolean save_txt_file = db.add_txt_file(id,
                       readFile(path));
     if (save_txt_file){
         Toast.makeText(this, "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

private byte[] readFile(String file) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),file);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int len; (len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TAG","error " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
    }
    return bos != null ? bos.toByteArray() : null;
}
```

The `path` gives this in log `Download/Link_on.txt` and the `readFile(path)` returns [49, 10, 48, 48, 58, 48...... but it is still failing to save the text file in db. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `want to save text file in sqlite ` There is no text file in your code. The only thing we see is that you try to save a bytearray as blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CREATE` statement of the table you have defined the column `POSITION` as `NOT NULL`, but in the method `add_txt_file()` you don't supply a value.

Add something like this line:

```
cv.put(POSITION, "some value");
```

Comment: But I have created many methods in such way and they are working fine. Also I am trying to assign a text file to a certain id, and I don't need a position in it.

Comment: I have added a method above that I am currently using with just two values.

Comment: @aawasi You can't add a new row to the table without a value for POSITION.. If you don't need the position then you should not have defined it as NOT NULL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, NOT NULL was the problem in the end. I removed that and it worked.

Comment: forpas if you don't mind I have this problem I have been struggling for months. If you take a look at this I would be very grateful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777725/why-are-highlighted-items-lost-after-scrolling-in-recylerview-android

Comment: @aawasi that issue is specifically about android and I can't help you with that.